# How to invoke a list of callbacks that return a Future one after another

Tags: scala, future

I need a mechanism to invoke a number of callbacks asynchronously... so I've implemented the following class:

```
class AsyncCallbacks[T] {

  private val callbacks = new ListBuffer[T => Future[Unit]]()

  def +=(f: T => Future[Unit]) = callbacks += f
  def -=(f: T => Future[Unit]) = callbacks -= f

  def invoke(data: T) = Future.sequence(callbacks.map(_(data)))
}

...

def f1(i: Int) = Future { println(i) }
def f2(i: Int) = Future { println(i) }

val callbacks = new AsyncCallbacks[Int]
callbacks += f1
callbacks += f2
callbacks.invoke(5)
```

`callbacks.invoke` produces a `scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Unit]]`... and I'm wondering whether there is a better and more efficient way to invoke all the registered callbacks without generating a useless list of `Unit`s.

The implementation above has also another problem... let's suppose we have the following methods...

```
def l1 = Future { List.fill(5)("1") }
def l2 = Future { List.fill(5)("2") }
```

... and then I invoke them like this:

```
for {
  a <- l1
  b <- l2
  c <- callbacks.invoke(5)
} yield b
```

`callbacks.invoke` works... but it looks like it never returns...

**EDIT**

OK, I've tried to re-implement my `AsyncCallbacks` class using scalaz as suggested by [I.K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3248346/i-k):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

class AsyncCallbacks[T] {

  private val tasks = new ListBuffer[Task[T => Future[Unit]]]()

  /** Gets the number of callbacks registered. */
  def count = tasks.length

  /** Clears all the registered callbacks. */
  def clear = tasks.clear

  /* Adds the specified function to the list of callbacks to be invoked. */
  def +=(f: T => Future[Unit]) = tasks += Task(f)

  /** Invokes all the registered callbacks. */
  def invoke(data: T) = Future { Task.gatherUnordered(tasks).map(_.map(_(data))).run.length }
}
```

And here is its usage:

```
def f1(i: Int) = Future { println(i) }
def f2(i: Int) = Future { println(i) }

val callbacks = new AsyncCallbacks[Int]()
callbacks += f1
callbacks += f2
callbacks.invoke(4) // prints 4 two times (f1 + f2)
```

Now just execute the code above from the REPL... and then try to invoke `callbacks.invoke(4) many many times and you'll see that your are no longer able to exit the REPL (it remains blocked and you have to exit with CTRL-C). I think this could be a problem in a real app.

Comment: Are you open to using `Scalaz`?

Comment: wow... yes, but I don't know it...

Comment: If you don't care if the callback functions finnish successfully (*without generating a useless list of Units*), you could just do `callbacks.foreach(_(data))` which will give you `Unit` as a result type.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your post that regardless of the type of data you want to put into the body of the `Future` you want it to be completed and be notified of that.

In Scalaz, it would be modelled as a `Task` which is essentially a `Future` underneath but comes with additional functionality.

Some examples,

```
scala> import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

scala> val tasks = (1 |->  5).map(n => Task { Thread.sleep(100); n })
tasks: List[scalaz.concurrent.Task[Int]] = List(scalaz.concurrent.Task@72b64eae, scalaz.concurrent.Task@3f6a6af, scalaz.concurrent.Task@5ba0314c, scalaz.concurrent.Task@36718c9f, scalaz.concurrent.Task@767277c1)

scala> Task.gatherUnordered(tasks).run
res10: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2, 3, 5)

scala> Task.gatherUnordered(tasks).run
res11: List[Int] = List(3, 1, 2, 4, 5)

scala> Task.gatherUnordered(tasks).run
res12: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 3, 4, 5)
```

As you can see, each time a run of these tasks is done, the output is different. The `Task` implementation is nondeterministic.

Taking your example,

```
scala> val tasks = List(Task{1},Task{2})
tasks: List[scalaz.concurrent.Task[Int]] = List(scalaz.concurrent.Task@2858b10a, scalaz.concurrent.Task@3782f5d8)

scala> Task.gatherUnordered(tasks).run
res13: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> val tasks = List(Task{List.fill(5)("1")}, Task{List.fill(5)("2")})
tasks: List[scalaz.concurrent.Task[List[String]]] = List(scalaz.concurrent.Task@1c8dd945, scalaz.concurrent.Task@71f8e5ff)

scala> Task.gatherUnordered(tasks).run
res17: List[List[String]] = List(List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Just tried... but see my updated post. I've re-implemented my `AsyncCallback` class using scalaz, but as with the old implementation the REPL remains blocked after a few tries.

Comment: Why do you still need your `AsyncCallback`? There is a `runAsync` method as well in Scalaz.

Comment: In my real app, I have a set of functions `T => Future[Unit]` to be invoked in a for comprehension like this: `for {
  transactions <- Future.sequence(orders.map { order =>
    for {
      transaction <- createTransaction(order.id)
      _ <- myCallbacks(transaction)
    } yield transaction
  })
}`

Comment: Use the `runAsync` method and pass a function into its body to call when each task completes. Alternatively you can use the `Async` scala library if Scalaz is not that familiar to you.